# Tracking if user has logged out from facebook in a new browser tab, when working with Facebook php sdk

Tags: php, session, facebook-php-sdk

I'm working on a facebook app using php sdk. I have one small problem with my app, after the user has logged into my app, if the user logs out of facebook from a new browser tab,after which any action on my app should be redirect back to login page saying user has logged out. but in my case my app is still working, even though he was logged out .so can anyone help me on this.

**Note:**
 I'm not using any logout URL in my app page. I  can directly destroy the session by calling `$facebook->destroySession()`, but I don't know how do I conditional do it,since I can't know when the user logs out of facebook(opening in new browser tab)

Answer (score 0):

If I logout from Facebook, while my app is running in an iframe, in another tab, I get a modal dialog "Login to Continue" served from Facebook. (using chrome)

If the same App is running outside Facebook (no iframe) in another tab, and I logout from Facebook, my App detects that the Facebook session is ended.

That's because I check on every page load if there is a valid Facebook user ;-)

My guess is that you don't check on every page load if the user is logged in.....

(or you have a funny browser that does not share cookies between tabs or something)

Comment: @ gedepasek i `m checking for valid facebook user each time a page is loaded ,by adding a condition which checks the value of $fbuser ($facebook->getuser()) in every page. even after adding this condition in every page, $fbuser still returns true(some positive value) even though the user is logged out of Facebook in a new browser tab.

Comment: What browser?, I use chrome, and doesn't happen for sure.

Comment: i`m using firefox,but i even checked in chrome as well, the response is same

Comment: Oh. Strange. Still it must be your code somewhere.... try my app and see if the same happens: https://apps.facebook.com/simpledemoen/

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. I could not found a way to detect if the user is logged in using the PHP SDK. However, when I combine the JS SDK, it can detect the session and set's the cookie correctly. Then I pick the cookie/session using the PHP SDK.

Be careful if you use my solution. Using the combined JS and PHP SDK, the AccessToken seems to lose it's persistence. the problem I have is getting the following error:
**OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.**

After reading, I discovered that this was a but that got fixed on pull 48 of the SDK:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/pull/48

That partially helped but now I get this error:
**OAuthException: Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time**

Summary: The combo SDK seems to work for solving your problems but the API obviously behaves buggy. I'm continuing my research and will post when I get resolutions.

Looking forward to hear what others have done to solve this matter